# ARCore – Can I put the model in other non-flat places?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have a scenario like this:

1. Create a huge frame/cage.
2. Switching to another model.
3. Put the switching model into the huge frame/cage originally created

Can another model be nested in `ARCore`/`Sceneform`?

Can ARCore or Sceneform be done now?

Any help will be grateful, thank you!